# Google Play services error

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk, google-play-services

I have installed Google Play Services and GPS Froyo at maximum. I get:

```
Google play services out of date. Requires 4030500  but found 32651130
```

Comment: How did you install the services. Through eclipse?

Comment: Yes, like a library uploaded and in the android project, mentioning the google play services library and installed in the SDK Manager to the last possible version.

Answer (score 0):

In /res/values/version.xml of your project, make sure that the version there matches the version of your Google Play Services /res/values/version.xml

If you are using a different language, then look in the values-xx for your language.

Answer (score 0):

go to your AndroidManifest.xml
replace the line

```
android:value="@integer/..."
```

with

```
android:value="4030500"
```